# Trying to start webpack dev server(Ubuntu)

Tags: javascript, npm-install, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to start webpack dev server on Ubuntu.

Tried npm install --no-optional

thinkpad-x220:~/Documents/Projects/javascript/webpack-starter$ npm run dev
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2

npm ERR! missing script: dev
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/joe`enter code here`/Documents/Projects/javascript/webpack-starter/npm-debug.log
thinkpad-x220:~/Documents/Projects/javascript/webpack-starter$

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: How can i resolve the error message?

Comment: well it looks like you are running npm run dev and npm is telling you that you don't have a dev script in pacakge.json

Comment: follow that https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server

Comment: Is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install webpack-dev-server
`npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

and then include this in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
   }
```

start the server with `npm run dev` from your cli